# C++ implicit conversions in operands to standard operators

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operators, implicit-conversion

I am having some trouble understanding the conditions under which C++ will use an implicit conversion. Suppose I have a class:

```
class SomeClass
{
private:
    int val;
public:
    SomeClass(int i) :val{ i } {}
    operator string() { return to_string(val); }
};
```

Why is it that when using this class with operators I need to cast to string? Why doesn't it just perform the conversion implicitly?

code:

```
int main(void)
{
    SomeClass sc = 4;
    cout << (string)sc << endl; //prints 4, compiles fine
    cout << sc << endl;//does not compile, no operator "<<" matches these operands

    string str1 = sc;//compiles fine, performs cast
    string str2 = "Base String" + sc;//does not compile, no operator "+" matches these operands
}
```

This question is more academic than practical as just using a cast is more readable anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`operator<<` overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) that gets used when you write `cout << (string)sc` is a function template:

> ```
> template <class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>
> std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&
>     operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os,
>                const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str);
> ```

This is because `std::string` is itself a class template, and can be instantiated with other types than `char`, and should still be printable if the characters are written to a stream of that same character type. In fact, that's exactly what happens with `std::wstring`, where `CharT` is `wchar_t` rather than `char`. That same `operator<<` works, provided you use a suitable stream.

When you write `cout << sc`, that particular overload is considered. That overload is then rejected because the compiler cannot deduce which type to use for `CharT` and the others. It would only be able to deduce the type if it already knew that the conversion would be performed, but the conversions are not considered just yet, they would only be checked in a slightly later stage.

If there were a non-template `operator<<` overload that took `std::string`, then it would work, `sc` would be converted implicitly.

Comment: So then, to be more compatible with C++ standard library functions (without casts), I should be writing implicit conversions to `basic_string` and not string?

Comment: @ApoorvaKharche No, `string` is a typedef for one particular instantiation of `basic_string`. Whether `operator<<` is written in terms of `basic_string<char>` or in terms of `string` doesn't make any difference, since they mean the exact same thing. Whether `operator<<` is written in terms of `basic_string<char>` or `basic_string<T>` where `T` is to be deduced does make a difference, and you have no control over that from your own class.

Answer (score 2):

`std::cout` doesn't accept a `std::string`.
It accepts a templated `std::basic_string`, the parameters of which are to be deduced.
See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) for further details.

Let's consider the following example:

```
#include<string>

struct SomeClass {
    operator std::string() { return ""; }
};

template <class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>
void f(const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator> &) {}

template <class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>
void f(std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator> &) {}

int main(void) {
    SomeClass sc{};
    f((std::string)sc);
    //f(sc);
}
```

It is similar to what happens in your case.
Of course, `f(sc)` doesn't compile for almost the same reason.

The problem is that to deduce the template parameters `SomeClass` should be converted to a `std::string`. To be able to convert it to a `std::string`, the compiler should guess that a valid overload exists and try to use it. Anyway, such a viable function doesn't exist from its point of view, for template parameters are still to be deduced and to deduce them the compiler should guess that an overload for `SomeClass` exists after a cast. It can't, because... And so on.

I haven't checked it, but I would bet that something similar applies to `operator+` too.

Comment: So then, to be more compatible with C++ standard library functions (without casts), I should be writing implicit conversions to `basic_string` and not string?

Comment: Shortly after this answer, the edit history made it look like you basically copied mine, but the edit history was misleading. You posted a wrong answer, deleted it when you realised that, and ended up fixing it. In the end, we simply posted fundamentally the same answer at the same time. If this should happen to be the reason somebody downvoted it, let that person please revert the downvote.

Comment: @hvd Exactly, we posted more or less two identical answers at the same time and, of course, mine was an edit of a previously posted wrong one. :-) ... Anyway, don't worry, it's not the downvote that hurts me, it's the fact that it is not explained and I cannot improve an answer if I don't know what's wrong for the reader.